# Conditional formatting depending on range of cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

My brain has stopped working, and hope to find some help here. I'm not super good with Excel formulas, so that's why I'm seeking help here.

On the left side is a list of seat bookings, being automatically updated from a Sharepoint list.

On the right, is a seating map, that I have made, to give a visual representation of which seats are taken and not taken on a specific date.

Each seat should have conditional formatting, so it will color the seat (cell background) red, if the seat is taken.

The formula I am using for Seat 1, which works:

```
=IF(AND(P1>=G2;P1<=H2;"N1"=$I$2);TRUE;FALSE)
```

If todays date (P1) is equal or higher than CheckOutFrom (G2) and lower or equal to CheckOutTo (H2), and is seat number N1, then seat 1 will have red background on the seat map.

I have tried both to apply it to entire column G, H and I, or range of cells, for example from G2 to G10 (G2:G10), but then the conditional formatting breaks.

Anyone have an idea on how this could work?

[Overview of the Excel sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VnkmU.png)

Comment: Remember to lock your references. So P1 should be $P$1, G2 should be $G2 and H2 should be $H2. Lastly, your I2 reference should probably be $I2. But I haven't really looked closely at this to fully understand the logic.

Comment: Thanks, for some reason it seems to be working both ways :)